# Merge tags 'og' and 'organic-groups'

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Please consider merging [og](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/og) and [organic-groups](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organic-groups); "og" is always used as shorthand for Drupal's "Organic Groups."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That makes sense, I've added the synonym.

Comment: Great.  Thanks, @googletorp.